# Flutter bottomNavigationBar error 'Page value is only available after content dimensions are established.'

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a problem with my bottomNavigationBar in Flutter. When i add a bottomNavigationBar before page loaded i get this error.

```
 bottomNavigationBar:  _buildnavigationBar()
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue.

```
bottomNavigationBar: (_controller.hasClients )  ? _buildnavigationBar() : Row() ,
```